# IgGrid datasource local filter onClick

Tags: javascript, ignite-ui

I am using ignites ig.datasource like so:

```
 ds = new $.ig.DataSource({
                                type: "json",
                                callback: renderTable,
                                dataSource: js,
                                paging: {
                                    enabled: true,
                                    pageSize: 10,
                                    type: "local"
                                },
                                schema: jsonSchema,
                                filtering: {
                                    type: "local",

                                },

                            });
```

I am filtering on click of radio buttons..

```
 $(document).change('input:radio[name="inlineRadioOptions"]', function (e) {
     var t = e.target.value;
     ds.filter([{
         fieldName: "Type", expr: t, cond: "equals"
     }], "AND", true);
     ds.dataBind();
 });
```

And this returns the filteredData in the ds, but i cant seem to rebind the grid with these values..see attached image.
[image: ds]

Thanks..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about creating new datasource using the [filtered data](http://www.igniteui.com/help/api/2016.2/ig.datasource#methods:filteredData) from the initial datasource?

```
newDS = new $.ig.DataSource({
    type: "json",
    callback: renderTable,
    dataSource: ds.filteredData(),
    paging: {
        enabled: true,
        pageSize: 10,
        type: "local"
    },
    schema: jsonSchema,
    filtering: {
        type: "local",
    },
});
```

And then use the `newDS` to create/recreate/rebind the igGrid.